# How to get all rows for 2 different values from SQL Server with a single parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

This is a part of my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStudentRegistrationDetails] 
        @TotalDataCount INT OUT,    
        @currentPage INT = 1,    
        @pageSize INT = 0,
        @Username  NVARCHAR(500) = NULL,
        @Userstatus INT = NULL,
        @Userregisteredby INT = NULL
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT 
                @TotalDataCount = COUNT (*) 
        FROM    VW_UserDetails  
        WHERE   RoleId=2
        AND     USERFULLNAME LIKE ISNULL(RTRIM(@UserName) + '%',USERFULLNAME)
        AND     CAST(ISNULL(Status,0) AS INT) = ISNULL(@Userstatus,Status)

        AND     CreatedBy = CASE    
                                    WHEN @Userregisteredby = 0 THEN 0
                                    ELSE CreatedBy
                            END
```

For `Status` my table has to values either 1 or NULL.

```
 AND     CAST(ISNULL(Status,0) AS INT) = ISNULL(@Userstatus,Status)
```

With this line of code, I am able to get values for 1 if I send 1 from my front end as  parameter & for null I am able to get all null if I send 0 from my front end as  parameter.

Actually I am sending 0 or 1 as parameter from RadioButtonList value fields. But I want to get also both NULL & 1 together also with a single parameter from from front end.

What should I send from front end or what correction do I need o get both ?

Guide me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the parameter to `2` and use `or @Userstatus = 2`.

Comment: @SantanuMaulik did you add the condition to the where clause?

Comment: Ya i did this but still no results .

Comment: AND     CAST(ISNULL(Status,2) AS INT) = ISNULL(@Userstatus,Status)

Comment: Do u want me to set like this? if i did so it is giving both if i send 1 , for 0 or null there is no result .

Comment: No, you should add the condition I have in the answer.